# Git repo through Tower on Mediatemple (gs)

Tags: git, repository, mediatemple, git-tower

I followed the directions on [Mediatemple's site here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1594/Using+Git#gs) and came up short, I couldn't get the local git repo to copy up to the server. I have ssh access and can get to the server and create a repo on my mediatemple server and access it through the command line, but when I try to link to it from my computer it won't connect.

I'm trying to use [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) and would like to create a repo on my server and then "Clone Remote Repository" from Tower and then be able to push commits I do locally up to the remote repo, obviously. But I seem to not be building the URL to the remote repo correctly. On the [Mediatemple page]((http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1594/Using+Git#gs) they seem to write the URL a few different ways.

```
example.com@example.com:domains/git.example.com/html/example.git

or

ssh://example.com@example.com/home/00000/domains/git.example.com/html/example.git
```

I can't get the local apps to find the remote git repos. If my domain is `joes.com` and I have created a git repo in a folder called `project`. What is the URL to that repo?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Drew here, from (mt) Media Temple. Although I can't really offer you an answer right here and now, I was wondering if you contacted (mt) Media Temple support about this yet. Although it is out of the scope of our support, we might be able to clear up some (mt) Media Temple specific questions you might have. If you call in or open a support request and explain what you've tried already, we might discover where you're going wrong. We're here 24/7 by phone, chat and Twitter if you need us. Drew J
(mt) Media Temple
@MediaTemple

Comment: You were right Drew, they helped me out. Thanks for posting that. 
For other peoples interested in this also, this article helped me also [git-website-howto](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)

Didn't answer all my questions but it sure helped. I finally have a server repo I can push my changes to and it will update the site. Thats a huge step forward for me. Thanks again Drew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drew was right, he totally helped me out and sent me to the right people at MediaTemple. Thanks!

I had very simple ssh problems, I was learning. The problem was I was trying to login to with the path and everything. What you need to do is ssh into the server then cd to where you want to be. 
$ ssh user@server.com
password:
$ cd where/you/want/to/go

then in the Git program you can just add 
user@example.com:where/you/want/to/go 
and that will work. THANKS!